# Search Only Works when Logged into Admin

Tags: admin, search

www.santasown.com
Search only shows products when logged into admin but still shows the filters on the left hand side.

Here is from the search.php

[image]
[image]

Comment: The code you've posted seems to be missing a chunk?

Comment: Just updated to the full code